# jquery .css() is not applying in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to move some images in my web page but what happens is the code works well in  chrome, Firefox and IE10. But when It comes to IE9 and earlier it won't work. Problem may be css3. But I need to move the slides in IE also. Please anyone help me by providing an alternative way.

Script:

```
target = (vertical) ? "translate(0," + target + ")" :  "translate(" + target + ",0)";
dur = (dur !== undefined) ? (dur/1000) + "s" : "0s";
slider.container.css({
    "transform":target ,
    "-moz-transition-duration":dur,
    "-webkit -transition-duration": dur,
    "-o-transition-duration": dur,
    "transition-duration": dur
});
```

**Edit: HTML**

```
 <div  id="flexslider-1" class="flex-flexslider flexslider">
 <ul class="slides"><li>  
 <div class="views-field views-field-title">   
 <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Nicole_Zitzmann">Nicole Zitzmann</a>    </span>  </div>  
 <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">
 <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Nicole_Zitzmann"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/oxavdDev/sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Nicole%20Zitzmann.jpg?itok=-7p1j_PM" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
 <li>  
 <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Melanie_Beer">Melanie Beer</a></span>  </div>  
 <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Melanie_Beer"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Melanie%20Beer.jpg?itok=2a6CrwFK" width="150" height="150" alt="Melanie Beer" title="Melanie Beer" /></a></div>  </div></li>
 <li>  
<div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Juan_Bolivar_Gonzalez">Juan Bolivar Gonzalez</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Juan_Bolivar_Gonzalez"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Juan%20Bolivar%20Gonzalez.jpg?itok=FlkwxHKX" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Alex_Caputo">Alex Caputo</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Alex_Caputo"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Alex_1.jpg?itok=RMSQMJUv" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Emma_Dixon">Emma Dixon</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Emma_Dixon"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Emma%20Dixon_0.jpg?itok=jQaCMqWs" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Constantina_Fotinou">Constantina Fotinou</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Constantina_Fotinou"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/ConstantinaFotinou.jpg?itok=1zs5Ozyc" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Bevin_Gangadharan">Bevin Gangadharan</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Bevin_Gangadharan"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/bevin_0.jpg?itok=DrPlXDjd" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Michelle_Hill">Michelle Hill</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Michelle_Hill"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Michelle.jpg?itok=sB91t6jb" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=JL_Kiappes">J.L. Kiappes</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=JL_Kiappes"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/JL%20Kiappes.jpg?itok=BWWk8dYA" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Abhinav_Kumar">Abhinav Kumar</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Abhinav_Kumar"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Abhinav.jpg?itok=KLnzz1L-" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Jo_Miller">Jo Miller</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Jo_Miller"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Untitled-1.jpg?itok=-SlZu5ik" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Ben_Oestringer">Ben Oestringer</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Ben_Oestringer"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/default_images/download.jpg?itok=e9dEkn3I" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Pietro_Roversi">Pietro Roversi</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Pietro_Roversi"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/pietro.jpg?itok=I1BIVIRl" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Andrew">Andrew Sayce</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Andrew"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="/sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/AndrewSayce1.jpg?itok=D-5ByU9B" width="150" height="150" alt="" title="Andrew Sayce" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Simon_Spiro">Simon Spiro</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Simon_Spiro"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Simon.jpg?itok=SBK4e1n1" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
<li>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-title">        <span class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Steve_Woodhouse">Steve Woodhouse</a></span>  </div>  
  <div class="views-field views-field-field-image">        <div class="field-content"><a href="/oxavdDev/?q=Steve_Woodhouse"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="sites/default/files/styles/flexslider_thumbnail/public/Steve%20Woodhouse.jpg?itok=MPYu6ILP" width="150" height="150" alt="" /></a></div>  </div></li>
</ul></div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[IE9 doesn't support css transitions.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FTutorials%2FUsing_CSS_transitions#Browser_compatibility)

use jQuery `.animate()` instead:

```
$('#element_id').animate({
    top: target + 'px'
}, dur);
```

just make sure `#element_id` has `position:absolute` (or `relative`) in css.

hope that helps.

Comment: This only answers half the question. OP needs an alternative solution/workaround.

Comment: @Gal I'm searching for an alternative solution.

Comment: @Gal I gave `$(slider.container).animate({left: target + 'px'}, dur);` but it is not working...

Comment: does it have `position` relative OR absolute ?

Comment: Yes `position` `relative`.

Comment: do you get any js error? i'll add a jsfiddle to demonstrate my approach

Comment: I'm not getting any error. I know animate will work. But in my case it is not working. Why I don't know. Other than `animate` is it possible to move the element by adding any `css` rule Like `tanslate`.

Comment: sorry man, IE9 doesn't support all this css3 animation stuff. you'r only friend here is mr. javascript... but let's investigate it a little more, can you post the rest of the relevant code? say- html?

Comment: which html element is `slider` js object?

Answer (score 0):

I would use Modernizr to detect when css animations are not supported. With Modernizr, it's as simple as:

```
if(!Modernizr.cssanimations) {
    //jQuery fallback 
}
```

As for rotating with jQuery I would use: https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: The `transform` property seems to indicate translation, not rotation.

Comment: rotation is just for an example